# What is the relation between topological entropy and Lyapunov exponent?

Tags: dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, ergodic-theory

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098596/why-is-the-entropy-of-a-dynamical-system-interesting/), topological entropy is defined. In [this book](https://smile.amazon.com/Chaos-Introduction-Dynamical-Textbooks-Mathematical/dp/0387946772/), the notion of Lyapunov exponent for, let's say a self-diffeomorphism from a smooth, closed Riemannian manifold to itself, is defined (in terms of the eigenvalues/singular values of the Jacobian matrix).

How are they related? Is the topological entropy of a self-diffeo $T: M \to M$ simply the maximum Lyapunov exponent over all $x \in M$?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Is this true: The topological entropy of $T = \tilde{\Phi}_{t=1}$, and therefore $\xi$, is the sup over all measures on $M$ that $T$ leaves invariant of the integral over $M$ of the sum of the positive Lyapunov exponents of $T$, $\displaystyle \sup_{\nu \in \text{ Invar}(T)} \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_k(x,v)\ d\nu$?

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that... you might look at Pesin's entropy formula.

Comment: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pesin_entropy_formula Got it; thanks

Comment: Is this true: The topological entropy of $h =\Phi_{t=1}$, and therefore $\xi$, is the sup over all measures on $M$ that $h$ leaves invariant of the integral over $M$ of the sum of the positive Lyapunov exponents of $h$, $\displaystyle \sup_{\nu \in \text{ Invar}(h)} \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_k(x,v)\ d\nu$?

Comment: It would be better to update your question in that manner, so it becomes more quickly visible to others (some of whom will undoubtedly know more than me about this stuff...)

Comment: So, it appears that Kolmogorov-Sinai entropy http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kolmogorov-Sinai_entropy is motivated by Hamiltonian mechanics, where one has that the flow of a Hamiltonian vector field preserves the symplectic measure by Liouville's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system#Examples (which, the symplectic measure can get "projected down" to the base manifold, which the projection of the flow presumably preserves and which, if the base manifold is compact, the projected measure can be normalized to be a probability measure).

Answer (score 2):

Trying to understand what your notation means, in general you only have
$$
h(f)\le \sup_{\nu} \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k(x)}\lambda_{k(x)}(x)\ d\nu(x)
$$
(really it is a bad idea to use $h$ for the map). This follows from the *Margulis–Ruelle inequality*.

The supremum runs over all $f$-invariant probability measures and the sum is over all positive Lyapunov exponents $\lambda_1(x)\le\cdots \le\lambda_{k(x)}(x)$ (unfortunately $k(x)$ may indeed depend on $x$).

But if $f$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism and $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the volume, then
$$
h_\nu(f)= \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k(x)}\lambda_{k(x)}(x)\ d\nu(x).
$$
This is *Pesin's entropy formula*. Therefore, under the same assumptions,
$$
h(f)\ge \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k(x)}\lambda_{k(x)}(x)\ d\nu(x),
$$
although you cannot add a supremum in general. However, if $\nu$ is also a measure of maximal entropy you obtain
$$
h(f)= \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k(x)}\lambda_{k(x)}(x)\ d\nu(x)
$$
and so also
$$
h(f)= \sup_{\nu} \int_{M} \sum_{i=1}^{k(x)}\lambda_{k(x)}(x)\ d\nu(x).
$$

Of course, all depends exactly on what you are assuming. Up to some technicalities on the $C^{1+\alpha}$  assumption this is the most general answer that you can get under general assumptions.